# Chrome Extension - How to get current page number of opened PDF file on browser?

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-chrome-extension

I opened PDF file on the internet with Chrome browser. And I want to get current page number of opened PDF file with Chrome Extension. How to do it?

Comment: It's not exposed so the only method is to "hack" Chrome by running it with --extensions-on-chrome-urls command line switch, then use chrome.debugger API to attach to the internal PDF viewer extension at chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/index.html and read its state/DOM via RDP [Runtime.evaluate](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime#method-evaluate).

Comment: thanks for info. I see, that way seem road of hard.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry to revive an old thread, but wondering if this was still the only way of reading the current page number of a PDF file (e.g. Is there a way of accessing page number using openOrClosedShadowRoot)?